# How to write Dictionary to a file?

Tags: swift3, nsfilemanager, nskeyedarchiver, swift-dictionary

I have a FileHelper class where I've implemented 3 methods whose job is to write a Dictionary contents to a file. Those methods are:

```
func storeDictionary(_ dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>, inFile fileName: String, atDirectory directory: String) -> Bool {
    let ext = "txt"
    let filePath = createFile(fileName, withExtension: ext, atDirectory: directory)
    /**** //If I use this method, file is created and dictionary is saved
    guard (dictionary as NSDictionary).write(to: filePath!, atomically: true) else {
        return false
    }
    */
    guard NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(dictionary, toFile: (filePath?.absoluteString)!) else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
func createFile(_ file: String, withExtension ext: String, atDirectory directory: String) -> URL? {
    let directoryPath = createDirectory(directory)
    let filePath = directoryPath?.appendingPathComponent(file).appendingPathExtension(ext)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (filePath?.absoluteString)!) {
        let success = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: (filePath?.absoluteString)!, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        print("\(success)") //** here is the issue I investigated. Always prints false.
    }

    return filePath
}
func createDirectory(_ directory: String) -> URL? {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let directoryPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(directory)

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: directoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return directoryPath
}
```

When I call `FileHelper().storeDictionary(aValidDictionary, inFile: "abc", atDirectory: "XYZ")` to write the dictionary, it fails with this procedure. But if I use

```
guard (dictionary as NSDictionary).write(to: filePath!, atomically: true) else {
    return false
}
```

it works.

What's wrong with `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(_:toFile:)` method??

And why `FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: (filePath?.absoluteString)!, contents: nil, attributes: nil)` always returns false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all `filePath?.absoluteString` returns the entire – even percent escaped – string including the `file://` scheme and the method expects a path without the scheme (`filePath?.path` - the naming is a bit confusing ;-) ).

I recommend to save a `[String:String]` dictionary as property list file. It's not necessary to create the file explicitly.

I changed the signatures of the methods slightly in the *Swift-3-way*. Further there is no need to use any optional type.

```
func store(dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>, in fileName: String, at directory: String) -> Bool {
    let fileExtension = "plist"
    let directoryURL = create(directory:directory)
    do {
        let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: dictionary, format: .xml, options: 0)
        try data.write(to: directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension))
        return true
    }  catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }
}

func create(directory: String) -> URL {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let directoryURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(directory)

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: directoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return directoryURL
}
```

PS: Instead of returning a `Bool` you could make the store method *can throw* and handle the error in the calling method:

```
func store(dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>, in fileName: String, at directory: String) throws {
    let fileExtension = "plist"
    let directoryURL = create(directory:directory)

    let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: dictionary, format: .xml, options: 0)
    try data.write(to: directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(fileExtension))
}
```

Comment: Well, I understand. But what you meant by **filePath?.path - the naming is a bit confusing ;-)**, I didn't get that

Comment: Your `filePath` is actually `fileURL`, an `(NS)URL` instance. A `path` implies to be `(NS)String`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Being silly . Another thing I want to know **is removing `_` from the method signature _Swift-3_ way?** Then when to use `_`s?

Comment: You have to pass `_` if you want to ignore the corresponding (external) parameter label. However the Swift 3 convention is to pass all parameter labels. Sometimes they are ignored for Objective-C compatibility reasons.

Comment: Glad to know that it's (`_`) basically used for the persons who are coming from Objective-C background to make themselves feel like Objective-C conventions. Right?

Comment: Sort of. But that's not the primary purpose.

Comment: One issue. `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString)` or `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path)` always returns false. I think the method signature `fileExists(atPath:)` stands for `fileDoesNotExist(atPath:)`. **Reverse of conventional way**. Can you take a look?

Comment: `fileExists(atPath` returns `true` if the file exists. But using my suggestion you don't need to create the file explicitly. Once again, never use `absoluteString` in the local file system.

Comment: Yes. That problem was solved. But I got into a new problem. That is, I tried to load my data and print it. For that reason, I tried `fileExists(atPath:)` method. But it seems, the method always returns false irrespective of whether the file actually exists in that location or not. I think this is a bug in _Swift 3_

Comment: It's certainly not a bug. Consider that absolute paths point to different locations in sandboxed and non-sandboxed apps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a swift 5 extension that should save any Dictionary where the `Key` and `Value` are `Codable`

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Codable, Value: Codable {
    static func load(fromFileName fileName: String, using fileManager: FileManager = .default) -> [Key: Value]? {
        let fileURL = Self.getDocumentsURL(on: .cachesDirectory, withName: fileName, using: fileManager)
        guard let data = fileManager.contents(atPath: fileURL.path) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([Key: Value].self, from: data)
        } catch(let error) {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }

    func saveToDisk(on directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory,
                    withName name: String,
                    using fileManager: FileManager = .default) throws {

        let fileURL = Self.getDocumentsURL(on: .cachesDirectory, withName: name, using: fileManager)
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
    }

    private static func getDocumentsURL(on directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory,
                                 withName name: String,
                                 using fileManager: FileManager) -> URL {

        let folderURLs = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let fileURL = folderURLs[0].appendingPathComponent(name)
        return fileURL
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let myDict = [MyKey: MyValue].load(from: diskDirectory, andFileName: diskFileName) // load
try myDict.saveToDisk(on: diskDirectory, withName: diskFileName) // save
```